# Attribute Error: Generator object has no attribute 'X'

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a method (python 3.4) in which two objects are passed. But I am receiving the following error. 
"AttributeError: Generator object has no attribute 'X'"

The code is as shown below:

```
    def method_name(node1, node2):
        parsed = []
        nextList = asyncio.Queue()
        iterations = 0
        while not ((newNode.X == node2.X) and (newNode.Y == node2.Y)):
            #code
```

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error. I tried printing the value of the attributes before using them in the while loop. I am able to succesfully print it. But I face issues when I try to use it in the while loop.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error* so are we, until we know what `node2` and `newNode` are

Comment: newNode is pointed to node1. node1 and node2 are two objects of a class which have properties like X, Y, ...

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [mcve].